# insert credentials into the windows login popup

Tags: powershell, authentication, credentials

I've been trying to create a script that would insert some credentials automatically into the standard windows login screen to a reports server.

what i have so far:

```
$ie = new-Object -com internetexplorer.application;
$ie.visible = $true;
$ie.navigate($url);
while ($ie.Busy -eq $true)
{
    start-sleep -milliseconds 1000;
}
$ie.Document.getElementById(“user_email”).value = $username
$ie.Document.getElementByID(“user_password”).value=$password
$ie.Document.getElementById(“commit”).Click();
$ie.fullscreen = $true;
$cmd.Quit();
```

this script works fine when using normal websites (ones where browser is in the website itself)

but what do I need to change it to be able to insert my credentials when prompted for auth before loading the website? (the windows security window)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found solution, it's not pretty, but it works:

```
$wshell = New-Object -com WScript.Shell
$wshell.Run("iexplore.exe $url")
Start-Sleep 1

$wshell.sendkeys("$username")
$wshell.sendkeys("{TAB}")
$wshell.sendkeys("$password")
$wshell.sendkeys("{TAB}")
$wshell.sendkeys("{ENTER}")
```

if I find a better solution, I'll make sure to post it, or feel free to post your own :P